# for loop not working when appending object in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, loops, object

I'm trying to append the object from the array. I try to loop through the array but it only appends one element of the array to the object.
fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/maherafrasiab/9ehkfvoc/3/

Edited:

```
    var shers = {};
// the .pbgmain will return the following array.
    var all = [{sher: "some text"},{sher: "some text"},{sher: "some text"}];
//basically i want to convert the above array into object.
    var data = $('.pbgmain').each(function(i) {
        datas = $(this).text().trim(); 
        all.push({sher: datas})  
        for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            shers = all[i];
        }
    });
```

Comment: You keep overwriting `shers`. What did you intend `shers` to be? What would be its properties?

Comment: @trincot these are collection couplets of poems in the Urdu language. Its properties would be every single couplet which sher.

Comment: Why are you iterating exactly `10` times? What if there's less than 10 items?

Comment: It isn't meaningful to "append values" to an `object`. An `object` only contains keyed properties (i.e. named properties). I think you're misunderstanding how JavaScript's `object` and `array` types work.

Comment: @Dai the array contains 10 elements. that is what I'm iteratinng

Comment: @MaherAfrasiab You are mistaken: **the array does not contain 10 items** when the `each` callback function runs for the first time, it will actually be empty. It will only contain 10 items if `$(".pbgmain")` returns 10 jQuery objects **after** the `each` callback runs. In which case, move the `for()` loop to be **outside** the `each` callback.

Comment: @Dai I'm not an expert. Can you give me a better way in which I can add more keyed properties to the object?

Comment: I can't because you haven't explained exactly what output you expect (ideally in JSON). I can try to guess what you're after, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Forgive my cultural ignorance but I don't know what a "sher" is - can you please explain what you mean by this: "these are collection couplets of poems in the Urdu language. Its properties would be every single couplet which sher.". Also, **please post the HTML** that you're reading from so we can see the document structure.

Comment: @Dai I have edited the question for better understanding

Comment: @MaherAfrasiab Thank you for the clarification, I think my answer should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the `.pbgmain` will return the following array.
>
> ```
> var all = [{sher: "some text"},{sher: "some text"},{sher: "some text"}];
> ```

You just need this ([and you don't need to use jQuery!](https://blog.garstasio.com/you-dont-need-jquery/)):

```
const elements         = document.querySelectorAll( '.pbgmain' );
const elementArray     = Array.from( elements );
const elementTexts     = elementArray.map( e => e.textContent.trim() );
const asArrayOfObjects = elementTexts.map( text => ( { sher: text } ) );
console.log( asArrayOfObjects );
```

This can be shortened to this if you want to be more *succint*:

```
const asArrayOfObjects = Array.from( document.querySelectorAll( '.pbgmain' ) ).map( e => ( { sher: e.textContent.trim() } );
console.log( asArrayOfObjects );
```

Comment: It is giving me cannot read property of undefined.

Comment: but the problem is I don't want the array of objects. I want the single object.

Comment: @MaherAfrasiab I can't really help you further unless you create a JSFiddle or Snippet **with the original HTML**, as well as example JSON that shows the kind of output you want.

Comment: here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/maherafrasiab/9ehkfvoc/3/

Comment: @MaherAfrasiab The example you gave as "`{sher: "some text to be selected"},{sher: "some text to be selected"},{sher: "some text to be selected"}`" is invalid. You cannot use the same name (key) for different properties: you can either have an array of strings, an array of separate objects (where each object has the `sher` property), or a single object with different property names.

Comment: @MaherAfrasiab The HTML in your example is probably invalid `<div class='.pbgmain'>`: the `class=""` attribute should not contain dot characters. Did you mean `<div class='pbgmain'>` instead?

Comment: @MaherAfrasiab This works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/b8gox3py/1/